# How to capture touched event on angular reactive form field?

Tags: angular, typescript

I've been searching for a solution on this but can't find what I'm looking for. I have this form and as soon as any field gets touched I want to console out a message in **ngOnInit**. So far if I enter a value in any field I can show a message (**"You entered a value"**), but I want to be able to show a message when user **touches** the field. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Here's my code.

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bg3fm6?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)
Thanks a lot in advance!

```
 ngOnInit() {
 this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(res => {
  console.log("You entered a value");
  // Here I want to show a message ("A field has been touched") when any field of the form gets touched
 })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't anything available out of the box for forms, AFAIK.

I guess you could leverage `HostListener` that is triggered for example in what dom event you want, for example `focusin`. You can have that in the component, or create a separate directive.

Sample:

```
@HostListener('focusin', ['$event']) onFocus(event) {
  console.log('a field was focused!')
}
```

Hopefully this is a suitable work-around (I guess it would be classified as one?)

Comment: Is there a way to create a directive using your code and apply it to the whole form rather then adding the directive to each field?

Comment: @HenryDev Looks okay to me? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qfrsff?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thanks a lot bro!!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! :)

Comment: @HenryDev how have you used this approach? have you wrote the same logic in both places (inside valueChange and inside onFocus)?

Answer (score 2):

Use the **(mousedown)** event in Angular

Here is a quick demo
[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u7b4of)

Comment: I tried that before, but the problem with that is that I will have to add the mousedown event to every single field in the form and my form has 20+ fields so the view will have a bunch of mousedown events all over and it doesn't seem to be a good practice. I'm trying to accomplish this ONLY from the component